# How to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_{i,j}^{2} = \frac{k}{n}$ iff $x_{i,j}=\frac{1}{n} \forall i,j$ when $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_{i,j}=1$

Tags: summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_{i,j}=1$ $\forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k\}$.

How to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x_{i,j}^{2} \geq \frac{k}{n}$ and that we have equality if and only if $x_{i,j}=\frac{1}{n} \forall i,j$.

I am trying to understand a theorem that uses it. It seems that it is standard, but I was not able to find the original source.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is basically Cauchy-Schwarz, except that you wrote the inequality sign in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thank you @WhatsUp, I have corrected the inequality sign!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_j x_{i,j}=1$ for every $i$ then check that
$$
\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x_{i,j}^2\right) -\frac1n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(x_{i,j}-\frac1n\right)^2.\tag1
$$
Sum (1) over all $i=1,\ldots k$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x_{i,j}^2\right) -\frac kn=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(x_{i,j}-\frac1n\right)^2.\tag2$$
The RHS of (2) is the sum of non-negative terms, so it is non-negative. This proves the inequality
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x_{i,j}^2\right) \ge\frac kn.\tag3
$$
And equality holds if and only if the RHS of (2) equals zero, which holds iff every summand on the RHS of (2) is zero.

Comment: Thank you @grand_chat, I think this was exactly what I was looking for.